# Best way to create coordinates for checkers board

Tags: javascript

I want to create coordinates for checkers. Is there a better way to create them?

```js
let div = document.getElementById("example");
for (let i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
  const xAxis = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"];
  for (let j = 1; j < 9; j++) {
    div.innerHTML += xAxis[i - 1] + "" + j + ",";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="example">

</div>
```

Comment: "Better" in what way? The algorithm is so simple that there isn't much room to improve, and [codereview.se] is the correct place to ask how to improve code style.

Comment: @JJJ Maybe they are some tricks I didn't know

Answer (score 1):

The only thing i could think of is using Array.forEach on your array and using a table to enforce the column layout.

CSS 3 nth-child for styling?

```js
var table = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("table"));
["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"]
.forEach(function(letter) {
  var tr = table.appendChild(document.createElement("tr"));
  for (var num = 1; num <= 9; num++) {
    var td = tr.appendChild(document.createElement("td"));
    td.innerHTML = letter + num;
  }
});
```

```css
tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(even) {
  background: red;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(odd) {
  background: red;
}
```